# Django - React production Deployment Using Apache | Either React or Django Working

Tags: django, python-3.x, reactjs, apache2, digital-ocean

I'm trying to run Django and React app together on Digital Ocean Server using apache2. I am facing an issue on adding WSGIScriptAlias

If, I am adding WSGIScriptAlias then django API working fine but react stopped working.
`WSGIScriptAlias / /proProjects/Portal/ApprovalSystem/wsgi.py`

else,
If, I remove `WSGIScriptAlias` then react app is working fine.

This is my syntax for `wsgi.py`

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ApprovalSystem.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Apache Configuration:

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend
  WSGIPassAuthorization on
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

```
<Directory /var/www/frontend>
    RewriteEngine on
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</Directory>
```

Require all granted

WSGIDaemonProcess proactProjects python-path=/proProjects/ python-home=/proactProjects/venv
WSGIProcessGroup proactProjects
WSGIScriptAlias / /proProjects/ApprovalSystem/wsgi.py

## Alias /static /proProjects/site/public/static

Please help?

Comment: How are you serving the react app ? And how are you serving your static files FWIW ?

Comment: I have added my static file under /var/www/

Comment: As per my understanding, Issue is with Wsgi server. Whenver I am adding WSGIScriptAlias it show no url found as serving only django.

Comment: Issue is with your apache conf and how you serve your react app and static files, not with wsgi. How to configure Apache to serve both Django / wsgi and static files is documented, a react app is basically just another static file, so if the only infos you care to provide are "I have added my static file under /var/www/ " no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I am serving like:     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend
  WSGIPassAuthorization on
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    <Directory /var/www/frontend>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>

Comment: In frontend directory, I have added my production build

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR POST - code in comments is totally unreadable. And please carefully re-read my previous comment: 1/ a react app is just another static file and 2/ how to configure apache/mod_wsgi to serve both static files and django is documented. If you have you static files working with Django, then just put your react app at the right place (in your statics) and it will work.

Comment: Also, i have added apache confg and edited my post.

Comment: Still, its trying to load urls from django and showing 404 (Page not found) Error??